# How do I create a list from raw_input in Python 2.7.2?

Tags: python-2.7

I have to write a program that accepts a sequence of average daily temperatures and put those temperatures into a list, but I can't figure out how.  What I tried below does not work.  Instead of giving me a list it just gives me the last input.

```
def main():
    #create a list to store the temperatures.
    tempList = []
    while True:
        dailyTemp = raw_input(
            "Enter average daily temperature or -100 to quit: ")

        # assign dailyTemo to tempList list
        tempList = [dailyTemp]

        print tempList

        if dailyTemp == '-100':
           break

main()
```

Comment: Hey, don't forget to do your check _before_ you append!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append to a list, you have to do `templist.append('thingtoappend')`.

In your case, you'd want something like this:

```
tempList = []
while True:
    dailyTemp = raw_input("Enter average daily temperature or -100 to quit: ")
    tempList = tempList.append(dailyTemp)
```

What the code that you posted does instead is, it says that the temperature that the user entered, *is* the list - so each time they enter a new temperature, it replaces the last one they entered.

Comment: Thanks. To mark this answer as a correct one, you should click the checkmark below the voting box. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer above does not work correctly because instead of append the new value to the list in this line `tempList = tempList.append(dailyTemp)`, it will try to append the value to an NoneType object and raise an error.

To fix it, you must just use `tempList.append(dailyTemp)`

The entire solution is:

```
tempList = []
while True:
    dailyTemp = raw_input("Enter average daily temperature or -100 to quit: ")
    tempList.append(dailyTemp)
```